# If $g(t,x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$, then decays uniformly in $t$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, examples-counterexamples

Assume we have continuous $g:[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \pm \infty} g(t,x)=0
$$
for every $t \in [0,T]$.

Then let $(t_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq [0,T]$ converge to some $t \in [0,T]$ and $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ diverge to $\infty$. Is it then true that
$$
\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} g(t_k,x_k) =0?
$$

Initially, I thought yes. I tried to use continuity to make $\lvert g(t_k,x_k)-g(t,x)\rvert$ small. But continuity is not uniform, such that there is noch guarantee the above expression goes to $0$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$.

So there might be a counterexample
, although I do not see it…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function
$$g(t,x) = (1+t)^{-e^{|x|}}-e^{-|xt|}.$$
It follows that $g:[0, T]\times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty} g(t,x) = 0$ for all $t$.

Now, we take the sequence $x_{k} = \ln(k)$, and $t_{k} = \frac{1}{k}$. We have that $x_{k} \to \infty$ and $t_{k} \to 0 \in [0,T]$. However,
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} g(t_{k},x_{k}) = \lim_{k\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{-e^{\ln(k)}} -\frac{1}{e^{\ln(k)\frac{1}{k}}} = \lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{1}{\left( 1 + \frac{1}{k} \right)^{k}}-\frac{1}{k^{\frac{1}{k}}} = \frac{1}{e}-1 \not= 0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Counter-example: Let $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be any continuous function that satisfies $h(0)=1$ and $h(x)=0$ if $|x|\geq 1$. Then define $g:[0,1]\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
$$\boxed{g(t,x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} h(x-1/t) & \mbox{ if $t>0$} \\ 0 & \mbox{else}\end{array}\right.} $$
Then we have for all $t \in [0,1]$:
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} g(t,x) = 0 $$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty} g(t,x)=0$$
Using $t_k=1/k$ and $x_k=k$ for $k \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ we have:
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} g(1/k,k) = h(0)=1$$
It remains to show $g$ is continuous. It suffices to check it is continuous at $(0,x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. In case this is a homework question, I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you! It is not a homework question, just my mere lack of creativity. :)